# Rails with MongoID Embedded Doc No Mapping To My Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

This is probably an issue on my part I have been struggling through some Rails and mongo samples to get up to speed (This is all for learning not for work.)  This current project I get a JSON string from a api and I put that in mongo.  So changing the document structure is not really an option.  I then have been trying to map that into a Rails model so I can use the data.

The JSON is a report that contains many transactions that contain many LogLines.

Snippet from a doc

```
    < Report _id: 583 c3baac0baf90a7ee26f6e,
  ReportName: "PtSomIntPerfThreeLevelTest-1480341940187", 
  TestName: "PtSomIntPerfThreeLevelTest", 
  Transactions: [{
    "colId" => "50437d6c-49c1",
    "InfoPlate" => "[0SXdokPL-R13VQZwi]",
    "rowId" => "1",
    "sortDate" => 1480341975952,
    "transactionType" => "REQUEST",
    "description" => "description text for my document",
    "startDate" => "11/28/2016 14:06:15",
    "startDateMS" => 1480341975952,
    "endDate" => "11/28/2016 14:06:23",
    "endDateMS" => 1480341983069,
    "finalEndDate" => "11/28/2016 14:06:23",
    "finalEndDateMS" => 1480341983069,
    "completeDuration" => "7 seconds",
    "completeDurationMS" => 7117,
    "feedProcessingDuration" => "7 seconds",
    "feedProcessingDurationMS" => 7117,
    "logLines" => [{
        "id" => "1062b1ca-0f04",
        "timestamp" => 1480341975952,
        "transactionType" => "REQUEST",
        "transactionStep" => "RECEIVE",
        "collationId" => "50437d6c-49c1-438a-9b8",
        "runName" => "runName-1480341940187",
        "msg" => "Import default",
        "elapsedSeconds" => "0.0",
        "elapsedMS" => 0,
        "InfoPlate" => "[0SXdokPL-3rmxW3oH]"
    },
```

I have a report model, and a transaction model ( I will do LogLines after doing 1 at a time)  My report model does fine I can get a single report doc based on an ID and it returns the report.  I can then do a "report.transactions"  and get a json blob of the transactions (almost always multiple transactions in a report) BUT its not recognized as a transaction model (will post all code below) So I cannot say transaction.InfoPlate I get a no such method error.  I have relationships in my model but I also have a "  field :Transactions, type: Array" which in looking at the rails cast on mongoid is not in theres. Without that I get nothing so the relationship "embeds_many :transactions" does not allow me to get a report.transaction.  Sorry if that is confusing my Rails lingo is low. Short and sweat I want to get a report then get the transactions and be able to do transactions.ColID  and get the col ID .

My goal is to get a model for each part of the document report, transaction, LogLines.  I do not seem to understand how to do that.

Report Model (Works Fine)

```
class Report
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :ReportName, type: String
  field :TestName, type: String
  field :Transactions, type: Array
  field :ReportDurationMS, type: String
  embeds_many :transactions
end
```

Transaction Model

```
class Transaction
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :colId, type: String
  field :InfoPlate, type: String
  field :rowId, type: String
  field :sortDate, type: String
  field :transactionDate, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :startDate, type: String
  field :startDateMS, type: Integer
  field :endDate, type: String
  field :endDateMS, type: Integer
  field :finalEndDate, type: String
  field :completeDuration, type: String
  field :completeDurationMS, type: Integer
  field :feedProcessingDuration, type: String
  field :feedProcessingDurationMS, type: Integer
  field :logLines, type: Array
  embedded_in :report, :inverse_of => :transactions
end
```

Report Controller (Index Method) Debug logger is just there while I hack around

```
  def index
    @reports = Report.all
    Rails.logger.info("********* #{@reports.inspect} ***********")
  end
```

Transaction Controller (This is what I can't get to return a transaction as a model) I get a transaction back from @report.transactions but its just a string of json as opposed to a ruby model.  Or at least I can't call anything like @transaction.colId.  Just returns no such method. Transactions is an array there are many so I did try transactions.first.InfoPlate  but still to me it seems Rails just seems the transaction that comes back as a string of JSON not an object.?

```
    class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_transaction, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @report = Report.find(params[:report_id])
    @transaction = @report.transactions
    Rails.logger.info("********* report #{@report.inspect} ***********")


    @transactions = @report.transactions
    Rails.logger.info("********* transaction #{@transactions.inspect} ***********")

  end
```

My route

```
resources :reports do
   resources :transactions
 end
```

Comment: `field :Transactions, type: Array` lets Mongoid know that there is a `Transactions` field, `embeds_many :transactions` tells Mongoid that there should be a `transactions` array whose elements are hashes and those elements should be wrapped up in `Transaction` objects. Everything is case sensitive. BTW, just because the API is giving you a blob of JSON doesn't mean that you can't or shouldn't rearrange/rename things to better suit your application.

Comment: Based on my code above how would I get the value of a transaction? For example "transactionType"  for any given transaction in a report.  I can see Rails knows my report is a report object I don't think it knows my transaction is a transaction object.  I think I'm 95% their I just can't get to the end zone

Comment: Ok I went back through based on your post and cleaned up my case.  I have lowercase t for transactions I think using Transactions I have it now working.  I thought I was following a Rails convention but clearly was mixing my stuff.  Went through and changed all "embeds_many :transactions" to embeds_many :Transactions"    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above post made me go back in and match all my case and that seems to be working.